Question about the integrand space of stochastic integral wrt martinagles
I am reading the book "Introduction to Stochastic Integration" by Hui-Hsiung Kuo. In Chapter 5, he introduces the definition of stochastic integral wrt martingale:
$$I(f) = \int_a^b f(t) dM(t)$$
The integral is firstly defined for $f\in L^2_{\mathrm{pred}}([a,b]_{(M)}\times \Omega)$, where

Notation 6.5.2. For convenience we will use $L^2_{\mathrm{pred}}([a,b]_{(M)}\times \Omega)$ to denote the space of all predictable stochastic processes $f(t,\omega)$, $a\leq t\leq b$, $\omega\in\Omega$, satisfying the condition $E\int_a^b \left|f(t)\right|^2 d\left\langle M\right\rangle_t < \infty$. Here, $\left\langle M\right\rangle_t$ is defined to be the conpensator of $M(t)^2$.

However, I do not recognize the intergration $\int_a^b \left|f(t)\right|^2 d\left\langle M\right\rangle_t$ wrt to $\left\langle M\right\rangle_t$. What is it? Is it a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral for each $\omega\in \Omega$? If not, how should we define intgeral wrt compensators?
I don't quite understand why the author mentions the condition $E\int_a^b \left|f(t)\right|^2 d\left\langle M\right\rangle_t < \infty$ without first defining what is  $\int_a^b \left|f(t)\right|^2 d\left\langle M\right\rangle_t$. I notice this problem also exists in other lecture note.

Yes, $\int_a^b |f(t)|^2d\langle M \rangle_t$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral for each $\omega$.  Since $\langle M \rangle_t$ is a non-decreasing process, it has finite variation, and so $\int_a^b |f(t)|^2d\langle M \rangle_t$ can be defined pathwise.
More precisely, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, we can define a measure $\mu_{\omega}$ on $[0,\infty)$ by $\mu_{\omega}([a,b]) = \langle M \rangle_b(\omega) - \langle M \rangle_a(\omega)$.  Then $\int_a^b |f(t)|^2d\langle M \rangle_t = \int_a^b |f(t,\omega)|^2\mu_{\omega}(dt)$ is defined, for each $\omega$, to be the Lebesgue integral of $|f(t,\omega)|^2$ with respect to the measure $\mu_{\omega}$.
